# char*の値を const char * に　代入する方法

Tags: c++, c

char a* = "Tokyo";を　const char *b に代入することは可能ですか。
やり方を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: `char a* = "Tokyo";` は、`char *a = "Tokyo";`の間違いですよね。単に`b = a;`でいいかと思いますけど問題だと思ったのはなんでしょうか？

Comment: こんなのがある
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6245/const-%e3%81%ab%e5%80%a4%e3%81%8c%e4%bb%a3%e5%85%a5%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b/6270#6270

Answer (score 2):

質問されることが多いのはこっちのケースですけと。

```
const char *a = "Tokyo";
char * b = const_cast< char *>( a);
```

間違ってたらごめんなさい。
やむを得ない場合もありますが、まぁあんまりやらない方が良いかも。